# Beyond stuck - Install issue/s - please save me lol

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown

Alright.  Fresh install this week via USB to an asus laptop model Q503u.
Duel boot with windows. Install went perfectly fine.  After install the Ubuntu desktop loaded - everything was working fine,  prompted restart, restarted, dual boot successful- saw both windows and Ubuntu etc, selected Ubuntu and.....the screen went black.  This was almost a week ago and I'm trying to do classes on my phone.  Lol

From what I can tell and from what I have looked up obviously a graphics issue.   No biggie, I've downloaded those drivers before.  I'll just restart etc etc  Ya no. Nothing. I can't even access bios, I dont get anything on the screen, it doesn't even appear the screen is getting power.   I try a full shut down, multiple times both by pressing and by pressing and holding power.   No response to a single press, I get a shut down if I hold power, but immediately upon releasing the power button the laptop starts back up.  I have tried connecting to external monitors- even if the screen ironically broke at that exact moment it should still work on the external -nothing, ive tried booting from the USB, ive tried every key combination possible to access bios and even explored the possibility that my keyboard was misidentified by ubuntu.  I have also left it unplugged to drain the battery etc etc.

No matter what i seem to do the screen remains black and again doesn't even appear to be getting backlight power.   I can hear the the fan and disk power on.  The only other indicators I have of any kind are 1) upon shutdown by holding the power button i get a single beep, again as soon as power is released the laptop powers back up.  2) I have a solid white led light on the caps lock key no matter what, power light remains solid, disk light remains solid.  That's it.  That's all I got to work with.

Is there anyone out there that can help me lol? Please.  I am beyond desperate.

Comment: Try turning up the brightness.  If you can get into the BIOS/UEFI settings, ensure you have more time than 0 to press a key at startup.  Check the firmware version, and update from vendor if necessary. ...

Comment: Brightness is not something I had thought of or tried yet.     If this works ill lol at myself while crying tears of joy haha.    I can fix whatever is going on IF I can get to bios where I can do something, anything, point is I can figure it out from there.   This black screen and nothing else  will be the end of me.    I'll let you know how it goes shortly.

Comment: "*No matter what i seem to do the screen remains black*" and many other symptoms that you describe indicate a hardware fault unrelated to Ubuntu that coincidentally occurred around the time of your install. Ubuntu doesn't destroy backlights, has no way to deny access to BIOS during boot, doesn't destroy hard drives, and doesn't make your CAPS LOCK key light during boot.

Comment: Well it was worth a shot but i got nothing.    Tried multiple key combos.   Screen is still black.

Comment: I totally get that it could be a hardware issue that extremely coincidentally occurred the second that I selected ubuntu after install but again if that were the case I should have some type of response on the external monitor.  If it was a motherboard issue I should at least be getting beep codes.

Comment: Before doing hardware replacements, try a CMOS reset, and see if your pc has some sort of reset by holding down the powerbutton for 30 sec. Then if nothing, try booting without the hard disk (fro USB), a different disk, etc.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? Are you using an external monitor? Have seen others have issues with start up on external monitor, but do not know details.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how boot works:

1. When you turn on, basic checks of your hard-disk or solid state disk are performed
2. BIOS locates the master boot record, loads it, and executes it.

The fact that you don't see the GRUB screen suggests you may be failing at #1 or #2 above.

The fact that even the USB does not work tells us that it is not able to:
(a) Locate the MBR in the USB stick
(b) Lets say it locates it, it is not able to load it
(c) Lets say it loads it, it is not able to execute it

Your HDD/SSD and USB's MBR cannot be damaged at the same time, assuming the USB stick is fine, it has to be (b) or (c) above.

Based on your attempts with the "power" button, it could also be a power issue. When you turn on a computer, it looks for a "power-good" signal, once the power-good signal is received, the processor is powered and it will look for the location of the BIOS ROM startup code. It is possible that this may be failing as well.

I have a hunch it is the inability to generate the power-good signal, if it is not the power, then it could be (b) or (c) above.